# Comparing properties with data annotations using greater than

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I am looking for a datannotation that take two parameters Dependent property and Operator (eg: > , < , = )

```
[Compare('DependendentProperty', '<')]
```

Please suggest if we have any existing dataannotation that support similar functionality.

Comment: You will have to create a custom ValidationAttribute for this I think, have a look at this: [http://cncrrnt.com/blog/index.php/2011/01/custom-validationattribute-for-comparing-properties/](http://cncrrnt.com/blog/index.php/2011/01/custom-validationattribute-for-comparing-properties/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom validator attribute that includes your logic. It is really simple. Search for ValidationAttribute in msdn. example:

```
public class MyValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable {
public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules( ModelMetadata metadata,
     ControllerContext context )
  {
     yield return new ModelClientValidationRule {ValidationType = "[javascript function name for client validation]"};
  }

public override bool IsValid( object value )
  {
     // logic here
  }
```

}